# How to use intent-filter to filter a text pattern

Tags: android, android-manifest, android-xml, intentfilter

i want to use intent filter to filter a text pattern like: `* text *`

and i want this intent-filter show my activity in share text intent choosers.

How to?

Answer (score 1):

That is not possible. You cannot filter on the contents of extras, like the `EXTRA_TEXT` used for sharing text via `ACTION_SEND`.